# Iterate through multiple objects returned by sqlalchemy query filter

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I see a lot of questions about iterating through columns, rows etc.

However, I'm at a loss for how to do this with *objects*.

```
dog = Item.query.filter_by(category='ugly').all()
return render_template('dog.html', dog = dog)
```

I want to put something like this in a template

```
{% for d in dog %}
```

And access each table with `d.id`, `d.descr`, etc. How do I use the object in my template?

Comment: Exactly that way you did in question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's exactly how you do it: you pass the `dog` variable to the `render_template` function and use it in the template in a [for loop](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for).

If `Item` has [properties](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#literals) `a`, `b`, and `c`, then you could use them as:

```
<ul>
    {% for d in dog %}
        <li>{{ d.a }}</li>
        <li>{{ d.b }}</li>
        <li>{{ d.c }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You may want to rename your `dog` to `dogs` to make it more clear that it's a collection, though.

Comment: You're right, my problem turned out to be JS-related. Thanks